# Calling a method of an object's prototype

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

i'm new to JS and got the following problem:

Why is this not working / what is this code doing?

```
var Test = {};
Test.prop = "test property";

Test.Class1 = function () {
}

Test.Class1.prototype = {
    m1: function() {
        console.log(this.prop);
    }
}

Test.Class1.m1();
```

My understanding of this code would be:

1. creating a new object called **Test**
2. adding the property **prop** to **Test**
3. creating a new object called **Class1** in **Test**
4. adding a method **m1** to **Class1**
5. calling the **m1** method of **Class1** in **Test**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, even the prototype property of a function is an object. Prior to creating an object whose prototype is the one you've defined, `Test1.Class1.prototype` is just a regular object. Basically it works the same way as the following code snippet:

```
var Test1 = { prototype { m1: function() {} } };
// You're trying to call an undefined function!
Test.m1();

// This is fine
Test1.prototype.m1();
```

In the other hand, when you use the `new` operator, you're creating a new object whose prototype is the one set to the constructor function. And here starts the *magic*:

```
var Test1 = function() {};
Test1.prototype = {
    doStuff: function() {}
};

var object1 = new Test1();
// This works!
object1.doStuff();
```

When you access a property, JavaScript's runtimes inspect the object to find out if there's a function called `doStuff`, otherwise it looks for it on the object's prototype, otherwise it looks on the prototype of the prototype and so on...

Actually `new` operator is a [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). ECMA-Script 5 introduced [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) which makes everything more clear:

```
var Test1 = {
    doStuff: function() {
    }
};

// The first parameter of Object.create is
// the object that's going to be the prototype of
// Test1 object!
var object1 = Object.create(Test1);
// This works too!
object1.doStuff();
```

Probably you should check this other Q&A: [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Answer (score 1):

`prototype` chaining only works for instances created with the new operator.

Otherwise you will have to explicitly call prototype to access the method.

```
let testClass = new Test.Class1();

testClass.m1();
```

Also since you are trying to access the `prop` property.

```
Test.Class1.prototype = {
    m1: function() {
        console.log(this.prop);
    }
}
```

The call site is `Test.Class1`, the `prop` should be part of `Test.Class1` and not on `Test`

Comment: Not only. What about `Object.create` :D

Answer (score 1):

I changed up the names of things, but this should work.

```
var Person = function(){
    this.message = "Hello, world!";
};

Person.prototype = Object.create(Object.prototype);
Person.prototype.constructor = Person;

Person.prototype.greet = function(){
    console.log(this.message);
    alert(this.message);
}; 

var tom = new Person();
tom.greet();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of the prototype before you're able to use its methods:

```
var instance = new Test.Class1();
console.log(instance.m1());
```

Even as such, Test.prop is not part of the instance, and will not be accessible to m1

Edit: Here's a working example:

```
var test = function() {
  this.prop = "A property";
}

test.prototype.m1 = function() {
  console.log(this.prop);
}

var instance = new test();
console.log(instance.m1());
```